# Why must we do template <class/typename> T instead of just template T

Tags: c++, templates

Instead of

```
template <typename T>
void func(T arg) {/* something */}
```

why can't we do

```
template <T>
void func(T arg) {/* something */}
```

From cplusplus.com :

> The only difference between both
>   prototypes is the use of either the
>   keyword class or the keyword typename.
>   Its use is indistinct, since both
>   expressions have exactly the same
>   meaning and behave exactly the same
>   way.

It just seems like unnecessary boilerplate to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/ See the section on Non-type parameters for templates.

You need some keyword to distinguish type-parameters from non-type parameters.

```
template <class T, int N>
class mysequence {
    T memblock [N];
  public:
    void setmember (int x, T value);
    T getmember (int x);
};
```

Comment: Or even `template <class T, int N, template TT<int> >` , to show all three possible template arguments.

Answer (score 9):

Because template arguments are not always types.  You can have a template argument that is an integral value, for example, as in the case of `std::bitset<size_t N>`.