# Is the template syntax in c++ just template <typename T>?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to understand this [Function passed as template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174169/function-passed-as-template-argument?rq=1). Turns out that in some places I've read about templates, you declare them like this:

```
template <typename MyTypeName>
class ...
```

Now what does

```
template <void (*T)(int &)>
```

mean exactly? This is more like a question about **syntax** than of what the code does. As I understood, it makes a templated function that takes a function pointer, and this function receives the reference to an integer as argument.

However, I don't think it fits the syntax for templates. Where's the `typename` keyword? What is the general template syntax?

The closest I found is this: [Why must we do template <class/typename> T instead of just template T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560922/why-must-we-do-template-class-typename-t-instead-of-just-template-t). Apparently you can define 'constant' template arguments. So I guess the template syntax is this:

```
template <arguments>
```

where arguments can be things of the type: `typename T`, `int N`, `void T(int)`, and so on. If that's the case, what is the advantage of defining

```
template <void (*T)(int &)>
void doOperation()
{
  int temp=0;
  T(temp);
  std::cout << "Result is " << temp << std::endl;
}
```

like this, instead of doing

```
void doOperation(void (*T)(int &))
{
  int temp=0;
  T(temp);
  std::cout << "Result is " << temp << std::endl;
}
```

?

Comment: "non-type template argument"

Comment: And for your final question, compare what happens if you add a `static` local variable to both versions, and call with at least two different parameters.

Comment: You are most likely looking at a template specialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the template syntax in c++ just `template <typename T>`?

No. There're three types of [template parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters),

> - non-type template parameter;
> - type template parameter;
> - template template parameter.

The `typename` keyword is needed for declaring *type template parameter*, and `template` and `typename` keyword are needed for declaring *template template parameter*. Given `template <void (*T)(int &)>`, `T` is declared as a non-type template parameter (a function pointer).

And about why not just doing `void doOperation(void (*T)(int &))`, because we have to declare `T` as a *template parameter*, otherwise it'll be just a function parameter name.

Comment: This is likely to be neither of these, but a specialization.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Which one? `template <void (*T)(int &)> void doOperation()` ?